# C program reading and writing to binary files

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-io, binaryfiles

Hello this is the first time I am working with binary file in C.

I am trying to first write the data to the file and then I to read the same data from the file. But somehow I am not reading the data correctly (that's what I think)  because I think the file writing part has no issue.  And I am doing all of this in unix.

So basically I am trying to write and read data from the binary file in unix and I am not able to read the data properly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have attached the code and the output below so it is understandable:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char data[100];
    if(argc<2){
             printf("Usage: gift <textstring>\n");
     return -1;
            }
            int n = 0;
            int num = 0;
    char data[100];
    if(argc<2){
             printf("Usage: gift <textstring>\n");
     return -1;
            }
            int n = 0;
            int num = 0;
    int fd = open("gifts.dat", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_RDONLY);
    if((strcmp(argv[1],"new"))==0){
            for(int i = 2; i < argc; i = i+2){
                    int number  = atoi(argv[i+1]);
                    strcpy(data, argv[i]);
                    int length = strlen(data) + 1;
                    write(fd,&length, sizeof(int));
                    write(fd,data, length);
                    write(fd,&number, sizeof(int));
            }
    }
    else{
            printf("Not worked");
    }
    for(int k =0;k < ((argc-2)/2);k++){
            int length;
            char*name = NULL;
            int money;
            read(fd, &length, sizeof(int));
            name = malloc(length);
            read(fd, name, length);
            read(fd, &money, sizeof(int));
            printf("%10s: %.2f\n", name, money);
            }
     return 0;

     }
```

And then here is the output of the binary file

```
gcc -o gifts board.c
./gifts new patel 200 Ram 500
      : 0.00
      : 0.00
od -c gifts.dat
0000000 006  \0  \0  \0   p   a   t   e   l  \0 310  \0  \0  \0 004  \0
0000020  \0  \0   R   a   m  \0 364 001  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000034
cat gifts.dat
patelÈRamô{cslinux1:~/CS3377_hmb180006}
```

Make sure to use `alias gcc='gcc -std=c99'`before compiling with gcc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and please post text instead of images.  As your example replies on a binary file, you need to make that available for us to run your code.

Comment: I just edited it. Let me know if there is more to edit

Comment: Start by actually checking the results of every single one of those IO calls. Currently *none* of them are verified, and you're blindly assuming they all are going to work. You'll find at best that the second loop is using a file descriptor that was never rewound, and therefore there's nothing to actually read.

Comment: I did verify as much as I can. but as you are saying to verify, how can I verify

Comment: Remove all the commented out code, anything that is not required to demonstrate the problem. When you minimize the problem it helps you greatly figure out what the issue is (even without our help).  Still need the binary file (not sure there is a way to attach it to the question so you might need to host it externally like pastebin).

Comment: @eliesmith `read` returns a value. It should be checked. `write` returns a value. it should be checked. the `open` returns a value. it should be checked. literally every single system call in this code is unchecked. Heed the [Sixth Commandment of Henry Spencer](https://www.seebs.net/c/10com.html). As I said before, once you're done writing, the descriptor is positioned at the *end* of the file. You never rewound the file. What were you expecting to read?

Comment: @WhozCraig - Thank you. Other thought, `int number  = atoi("my cow");` will happily assign `0` to `number` without error.

Comment: Ok then is there any way to convert a string to number then? And then if that is returning 0, then why string is not being printed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem is with your `open()` call. You are attempting to open the file as both **read-only** and **write-only** at the same time. From **man 2 open**:

> The  argument flags must include **one** of the following access
> modes: `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY`, or `O_RDWR`.

Refactoring your code as follows works fine.

```
    char data[100];
    int fd = open ("gifts.dat", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY);
    int n = 0;
    
    if ((strcmp(argv[1],"new")) == 0) {
        for (int i = 2; i < argc; i = i+2){
            int number = atoi (argv[i+1]);
            strcpy (data, argv[i]);
            int length = strlen(data) + 1;
            write (fd, &length, sizeof(int));
            write (fd, data, length);
            write (fd, &number, sizeof(int));
            n++;
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("Not worked");
    }
    close (fd);
    fd = open ("gifts.dat", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY);
    
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
        int length;
        char name[100];
        int money;
        
        read (fd, &length, sizeof(int));
        read (fd, name, length);
        read (fd, &money, sizeof(int));
        
        printf("%10s: %.2d\n", name, money);
    }
    close (fd);
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/readwrite_bin new patel 200 Ram 500
     patel: 200
       Ram: 500
```

Additionally, you must validate all opens, reads, writes (and close - after write) by checking the return of each call to ensure is succeeds, or handle any error if it fails. You should replace `atoi()` with at minimum `sscanf()` or better `strtol()` as `atoi()` provides zero error detection and will happily accept `atoi ("my cow");`

Let me know if you have further questions.